# javascript function not being called

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea why the function won't call. Initially it was from the form with onsubmit="return checkFilled()" but I also tried just calling it with an onclick event in with a button and it never enters the function. Here is the code:

```js
function checkFilled() {
  alert("Entered"); //just to test if entering function
  return false;
  var currentBox = document.getElementById("livCost").value;
  if (currentBox == null) {
    alert("Not all preferences are filled out!");
    return false;
  }
  currentBox = document.getElementById("travOps").value;
  else if (currentBox == "Select") {
    alert("Not all preferences are filled out!");
    return false;
  } else
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkFilled()" method="post" action="recommendScript.php">

  <p>Cheap living cost :
    <select name="livingCost" id="livCost">
                <option selected>Select</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            <p>Travel Opportunities : 
            <select name="travelOps" id="travOps">
                <option selected>Select</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>     
            </select></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="loginButton" />
```

Why won't this run?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @AlonEitan There's an `alert()` before that.

Comment: Are you missing the closing script tag in the code you are trying to run or is that just an issue with copying the code over to your question?

Comment: Most likely you have a syntax error somewhere in your Javascript, and it's preventing this function from being defined. If you open the console you'll see the error message.

Comment: I guess it's a copy mistake, do you have a catch for that onsubmit?

Comment: Your problem is that you have this line `currentBox = document.getElementById("travOps").value;` between your `if` and the corresponding `else`. This is not allowed. Also you should close your tags (but this is not part of the reason why your code doesn't work)

Comment: Script tag is there it just didn't copy over. I don't have a catch for the onsubmit, but getting this error from log

Uncaught ReferenceError: checkFilled is not defined
    at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Comment: You have made a copy paste error and your code has Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else due to presence of a statement between if and else if statements.

Comment: @mmgross will try get rid of that, but would the alert not be called regardless of that?

Comment: Yes that worked @mmgross, thank you!

Comment: Nope, syntax errors happen before the execution of any code.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to close your script tag and the form tag, if still not working open javascript console to look for any syntaxe errors

Comment: Have you tried that to verify that this solves the problem? Actually that last part of your answer is a valuable advice, so I removed my downvote.

Comment: no i didn't but on submit will fire only if the form tag is closed otherwise there is no form to submit, i will test your code now

Comment: here is the full code https://jsfiddle.net/wjugs42b/ closing the script tag solve half the problem and moving one line between if and else if  solved the other half, you may wanna give me a vote up.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be bug in this code:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkFilled()" method="post" action="recommendScript.php">
```

Instead, try this:

```
<form onsubmit="checkFilled()" method="post" action="recommendScript.php">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

First off, change `<script>` to `<script type="text/javascript">` to make it safer, and in the end of your js code, make sure to put the closing script tag `</script>`

Comment: Have you tried that to verify that this solves the problem?